# SSI Jboss not including html (context issues)

Tags: apache, jboss, solaris, ssi, context.xml

Hi I hope that someone out there could give a clue on where to here. Here's the problem.

I have enabled SSI in some jboss under Solaris, I have the application web.xml configured as follows:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>ssi</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIFilter
    </filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contentType</param-name>
        <param-value>application/xml(;.*)?</param-value> <!-- also have tried here html(;.*)? -->
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>expires</param-name>
        <param-value>666</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>isVirtualWebappRelative</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

  <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ssi</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xsl</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
    <!-- the following mappings were inserted after -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ssi</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>ssi</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>*.shtml</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

So my problem is that the SSI is working for XSL files but not for HTML files. Also I put the Context issues in the title since I have a symbolic link to my app.war in jboss this is because I'm using a CMS and I need the files to be posted somewhere in the file system.

The two things I can think about this, is that either is something messing up with my multiple filter mapping declarations (which is very unlikely) and the other one is that jboss is not able to reload the context for this app.war

Also I put here some information about Context.xml since I think you might ask for it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" reloadable="true" privileged="true"/>
```

I will appreciate any pointers, I can't figure out what could it be

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just changed from filter to servlet and worked just fine here's the code

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>buffered</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>debug</param-name>
        <param-value>0</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>expires</param-name>
        <param-value>60</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>isVirtualWebappRelative</param-name>
        <param-value>1</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```